# Stripe payments, cannot get payment amount from checkout

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe 'checkout' to collect payments. I have used this successfully on other sites but this particular use-case is slightly different from my normal flow and is causing me problems. My customer sometimes has a choice to pay deposit or full payment. I present two buttons in this case, one for each payment type e.g.

```
<form name="myform" action="paymentpage.php">
... other form stuff
    <!-- Deposit payment button Stripe -->
    <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="abcd"
      data-amount="10000"
      data-name="My company name"
      data-description="Deposit payment"
      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-zip-code="true"
      data-currency="eur"
      data-label="Pay Deposit">
    </script>
    <!-- Full payment button Stripe -->
    <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="avcd"
      data-amount="{{ $stripeCostValue }}"
      data-name="My company name"
      data-description="Full payment"
      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-zip-code="true"
      data-currency="eur"
      data-label="Pay in full">
    </script>
```

I want to use cURL to make the charge after the customer has done their bit e.g.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_liveabcd1234: \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=eur \
   -d description="Deposit payment" \
   -d source=tok_89797oioououo
```

The Laravel controller which receives the posted data has the following Stripe fields included by default:

```
"stripeToken" => "tok_89797oioououo"
"stripeTokenType" => "card"
"stripeEmail" => "customer@whatever.com"
```

But I have no idea whether they paid a deposit, full payment, or the amount they paid. Is there a way I am supposed to know which button they pressed or is there a way to get more data from the Stripe payment? I can't figure it out. I can't include the amount or payment type as a hidden field because I don't know which payment button the customer will push.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you put both buttons in the same form. Because of this you don't know which one is clicked.

The easiest solution is to simply have 2 separate buttons and forms. That way, in each form you can put a hidden field that lets you know which button was clicked as the value gets submitted with the form.

Another solution is to use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom). This lets you have 2 separate buttons in your form and, in JS, add a handler to open Checkout on click. This also lets you easily track which button was clicked and then submit this information to your server once the token is created.

Comment: "The easiest solution is to simply have 2 separate buttons and forms." I was hoping not to have to do that as it seems rather hack-ish and not very elegant. So it looks like Stripe doesn't allow sending of any non-private transaction data along with it's token, token type and email address. I can't understand why not but if that's what I have to deal with then I guess there's nothing else for it. Thanks for taking the time to answer koopajah.

Comment: It would be nice to be have access to the data- properties

Comment: @Wittner but we do support this. You can put any input field in your form and it will be submitted with the token itself and it just works. the issue here is that you have 2 buttons in one form so there's no way for you to know which one was clicked. My answer covers in details the 2 options available to you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks koopajah. Fair enough. I am currently having to create two forms which feels wrong because I actually have an option for 'enquiry only' also, so the form and hidden fields are being repeated 3 times in all. I'll mark this answer as correct as it does solves the immediate problem and provides some more clarity. I will continue with this approach just to get the job done quickly and then refactor with the 'custom checkout' solution which looks as if it might suit better. Thanks again. Stripe is a great product.

Comment: Follow up to this question. I used custom checkout for the final product and it works as suggested. Many thanks.